# MYSQL join with where clause excluding matching value

Tags: mysql

I am confused with a basic query, I have 2 tables `employees` and `employee_time_off`. I wanted to fetch all those employees who are not off on any specific date.

What I have tried is,

```
SELECT
    employees.id,
    employees.FIRST_NAME
FROM `employees`
LEFT JOIN `employee_time_off` ON `employees`.`id` = `employee_time_off`.`employee_id` 
    AND `START_DATE` < '2019-06-30 00:00:00' AND `END_DATE` > '2019-06-30 12:59:59'
```

`START_DATE` is actually when the leaves start, `END_DATE` is when the leave ends.

So, in this case, employee with `id=1` shouldn't be in the result set. But the result set gets all the employees from 1 to 6.

[image: employees]

[image: employee_time_off]

Comment: i advice you to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) *"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc"*  which you have done... Also see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for help into providing beter user case with example data and expected results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `NOT EXISTS`?

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM employee_time_off eto
                  WHERE eto.employee_id = e.id AND
                        eto.start_date <= '2019-06-30' AND
                        eto.end_date >= '2019-07-01'
                 );
```

Note:  I'm not sure if the `end_date` should be `'2019-06-30'` or `'2019-07-01'`.  Your question doesn't have enough information (off the *whole* day or any part of the day).

Your version returns all employees because you are using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: off is for the whole day, even for multiple days like in between start and end date.

Answer (score 1):

from the SQL, we can't tell which table has the start_date and end_date columns. we suspect its the employee_time_off table. to reduce ambiguity, qualify *all* column references

We can add a condition to the WHERE clause, to throw out the rows where we find a matching row in time off.  Also looks like we need to do `<=` and `>=` comparisons to get the result we're after.

```
SELECT e.id
     , e.first_name
  FROM employees e
  LEFT
  JOIN employee_time_off o
    ON o.employee_id   = e.id
   AND o.start_date    <= '2019-06-30 00:00:00'
   AND o.end_date      >= '2019-06-30 23:59:59'
 WHERE o.employee_id IS NOT NULL
```

Note that with that query, we would get a different result if we had these rows in the time_off table:

```
 employee_id   start_date            end_date
 -----------   ----------------      -------------------
           1   2019-06-30 00:00:00   2019-06-30 07:24:59
           1   2019-06-30 07:25:00   2019-06-30 23:59:59
```

What should the query return when time off table contains a row like this?

```
 employee_id   start_date            end_date
 -----------   ----------------      -------------------
           2   2019-06-29 00:00:00   2019-06-30 11:14:59
```

The specification isn't clear.

---

Also, we tend to do datetime overlap checks with conditions like

```
WHERE  foo    >= '2019-06-30 00:00'
  AND  foo    <  '2019-06-30 00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: This returns only 1 record which I wanted to ignore, I have changed it to  
"WHERE o.employee_id IS NULL" it works as expected